# Compare variable format definition change

Tags: sas

I need to compare two data sets in terms of variable name, type, format, label (informat not provided in the data sets) in order to append and know the change across multiple years.

I know the options are PROC COMPARE and SQL comparison. But I want to control the output of comparison (then, SQL is preferred), and I am concerned about any change in format definition.

With SQL comparison, it's straightforward to compare variable name, type, label, variable format name.

For the two data sets I want to compare, the variable formats are defined by PROC FORMAT, codes saved separately in text files. Is there a way to compare format definition? It seems SAS can save format definition in a permanent/work? table.  Is there a comparison available to compare format name, type, categories, variable the format is imposed on?

Comment: What is your actual question here? SAS does compare format names, not the contents when determining that formats are different. I generally won't use PROC COMPARE for any comparison, and instead do a SQL comparison. It's easier to get your data in the form you want that way.

Comment: @Reeza My question is how to compare two data sets in terms of variable name, type, format and label. I think I can do SQL comparison for all except format definition. The two data sets actually have their variable formats defined from PROC FORMAT statements saved in two text files. Should I then just do compare of the two text files through something like Notepad ++?

Comment: You can get all of that information from the `dictionary` tables and then compare. If your question is how to compare format definitions, that's a different question and then the answer would be dump the definitions to a data set and proc compare those. You can access formats using `PROC FORMAT CNTLOUT`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit unclear what you're asking, but there are several options you can use to control the output from proc compare. Here's a couple that might be relevant to you, and you can always have a look at the documentation.

```
proc compare
    base=one
    compare=two
    outbase        /* Output rows which are in base table */
    outcomp        /* Output rows which are in comp table */
    outdif         /* Output differences between rows that are in both base and comp */
    out=three      /* Set table to send output to */
;
```

Comment: I want to compare variable names, attributes, not observations/rows.